# Shouldn't R: AsRef<[T]> should work for T=u64?

Tags: rust

On the following:

```
pub fn a<
        T: Copy,
        R: AsRef<[T]> 
    >(
        a_fn: &dyn Fn(&[R], &mut [u64]),
    ) 
{
    let mut result = vec![0, 3];
    b(&[1,2,3], result.as_mut_slice());
}
    
    
fn b<T: Copy, R: AsRef<[T]>>(_: &[R], _: &mut [u64]) {
    unimplemented!();
}
    
fn c() {
    a::<u64, &[u64]>(&b);
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=43d054772b15fa575cc75e87b4eb34d9

I'm trying to be generic on the type `R`, but eventually use a slice of u64. However, it looks like that `[integer]` does not implement `AsRef<[T]>`.

Error:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `{integer}: AsRef<[_]>` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:9:5
   |
9  |     b(&[1,2,3], result.as_mut_slice());
   |     ^ the trait `AsRef<[_]>` is not implemented for `{integer}`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <&T as AsRef<U>>
             <&mut T as AsRef<U>>
             <Arc<T> as AsRef<T>>
             <Box<T, A> as AsRef<T>>
           and 38 others
note: required by a bound in `b`
  --> src/lib.rs:13:18
   |
13 | fn b<T: Copy, R: AsRef<[T]>>(_: &[R], _: &mut [u64]) {
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `b`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

Comment: Are you sure this is what you mean to say? Right now, you're saying "`u64` should be `AsRef`-castable to `&[u64]`", but it makes no sense to `AsRef` a single value into an array.

Comment: Should this be: `b<T: Copy, R: AsRef<[T]>>(_: &[R], _: &mut [u64])` or `b<T: Copy, R: AsRef<[T]>>(_: &R, _: &mut [u64])`

Right now you are trying to make u64 be `AsRef<[T]>`, not `&[u64]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `b` to take `R` or `&R` rather than `&[R]`. `&[R] == &[AsRef<[T]>]` has nested slices which I take it is not your intention.

```
fn main() {
    let mut result = vec![0, 3];
    b(&[1,2,3], result.as_mut_slice());
}
    
fn b<T: Copy, R: AsRef<[T]>>(_: R, _: &mut [u64]) {
    unimplemented!();
}
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c408061d1fd7033da36b7ed1503af746)</sup>